# How to call or create two sequences in one TABLE of Oracle APEX 4.1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, sequences

I have made two sequences, Vendor_Id and Vendor_ReferenceNo, for the table Vendor. I want to call or add both the sequences in Vendor table.   But APEX 4.1 only gives the option of one sequence per table.  Is there any other method?

Comment: Sequences generate unique numbers and do nothing else.  They are for primary keys, usually synthetic or surrogate ones at that.  Why does your table have *two* unique identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to do this (as @APC mentioned in the comment, this is usually a sign of a flawed design), you can create a trigger on the table that selects from the second sequence and sets the corresponding column.

Comment: Yeah i have create tiggers for all the primary key sequences and it also works.. But the thing is that the primary key column data is not shown in other table column..i-e how to copy or show the primary key data in foreign key column in another table...